# How can I see best efforts on Strava?

Tags: strava

I have a free Strava account. In my profile on the Strava webpage, I can see my estimated best efforts. For what concern running I can see:

- 1k
- 1 mile
- 5k
- 10k
- Half-Marathon
- Marathon

After a run, Strava told me that I completed my best 400m effort. Is there a way to see (with a free profile) my estimated 400m best effort without remembering (and looking for) the specific activity in which I performed my 400m best effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a way to view 400 m efforts, except for 3rd party sites/web apps. A free option is [PB Viewer](https://benwebb.net/):

1. allow the app to sync with strava and import your activity data
2. in the activities view of the app, use the 3-dots menu of a column to select distances (400 m is an option)
3. click a column header (e.g. 400 m) to cycle through sorting options until you see an *up arrow* to sort the activities by best time for that distance

Other sites/web apps that offer a paid option to see 400m PR:

- [Strava Best Efforts](https://stravabestefforts.com/) -- only the last 180 days without a subscription
- [Strafforts](https://www.strafforts.com/) -- only 5K and 10K distances without subscribing